# Swift - Find the index of an array of dictionaries based on the value in the dictionaries using swiftyJSON

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, swifty-json

I am very new to programming, let alone Swift. I understand some concepts from previous attempts at programming so I have gotten further than ever before. I apologize if I am not clear in what I need.

I am pulling in JSON data of a list of alerts and I am trying to parse the data with swiftyJSON which I think is working out ok but I have run into a snag of trying to grab some data from some dictionaries within an array, and unfortunately inside a dictionary inside this arrary is where the email address is, and the different dictionaries use similar keys within each other.

I am going to show you my struct, fucntion and JSON data. Please help me grab the email address, service - its ID and its label. Also, there may be more than one Service as in the data shown and I need to capture all of them.

HERE IS THE JSON DATA:

```
{
"hasNext": false,
"data": [
    {
        "status": [
            1,
            "READ"
        ],
        "resolutionStatus": [
            0,
            "OPEN"
        ],
        "description": "There is some description here",
        "title": "Some Activity",
        "entities": [
            {
                "view_name": "audits",
                "type": "link",
                "parameters": {
                    "orgUnit": "/"
                },
                "label": "/"
            },
            {
                "type": "user",
                "id": "hidden@hidden.com",
                "label": "hidden@hidden.com"
            },
            {
                "type": "service",
                "id": 6666,
                "label": "someService"
            },
            {
                "type": "service",
                "id": 7777,
                "label": "anotherService"
            }
        ],
        "stories": [
            5
        ],
        "date": "2014-12-10T23:46:28.067000Z",
        "audits": [
            "ljBhqKQVOF9w",
            "pISQyT9iy9w",
            "oynGf2_CIw"
        ],
        "_id": "54fdad0dfd",
        "id": [
            14683,
            "ALERT_SOME_ACTIVITY"
        ],
        "severity": [
            5,
            "HIGH"
        ]
    }
```

Here is my Struct:

```
    struct AlertModel: Printable {
    let alertUser: String?
    let alertService: String?
    let alertTitle: String?
    let alertReadStatus: String?
    let alertResolutionStatus: String?
    let alertDescription: String?
    let alertEntities: Array <String> = []
    let alertDate: String?
    let alertAudits: Array <String> = []
    let alertId: String?
    let

     alertSeverity: String?

      // change description to print to console
         var description: String {
            return "User: \(alertUser)\nService: \(alertService)\nTitle: \(alertTitle!)\nRead Status: \(alertReadStatus!)\nResolution Status: \(alertResolutionStatus!)\nDescription: \(alertDescription!)\nDate: \(alertDate!)\nAlert ID: \(alertId!)\nSeverity: \(alertSeverity!)\n******************************************\n"
        }

        init(alertUser: String?, alertService: String?, alertTitle: String?, alertReadStat

us: String?, alertResolutionStatus: String?, alertDescription: String?/*, alertEntities: Array<String>*/, alertDate: String?/*, alertAudits: Array<String>*/, alertId: String?, alertSeverity: String?) {
        self.alertUser = alertUser
        self.alertService = alertService
        self.alertTitle = alertTitle
        self.alertReadStatus = alertReadStatus
        self.alertResolutionStatus = alertResolutionStatus
        self.alertDescription = alertDescription
        //self.alertEntities = alertEntities
        self.alertDate = alertDate
        //self.alertAudits = alertAudits
        self.alertId = alertId
        self.alertSeverity = alertSeverity
    }
```

AND HERE IS THE FUNCTION:

```
let jsonAlert = JSON(data: jsonAlertObject)
    if let alertArray = jsonAlert["data"].array {
        var alerts = [AlertModel]()
        for alertDict in alertArray {
            let alertTitle: String? = alertDict["title"].stringValue
            let alertReadStatus: String? = alertDict["status"][1].stringValue
            let alertResolutionStatus: String? = alertDict["resolutionStatus"][1].stringValue
            let alertDescription: String? = alertDict["description"].stringValue
            let alertDate: String? = alertDict["date"].stringValue
            let alertId: String? = alertDict["_id"].stringValue

            // Need to grab the type and label from each dictionary in the array of entities
            let alertEntitiesArray: Array? = alertDict["entities"].arrayObject
            var arrayIndex = 0
            var entitiesDict = ["" : ""]
            while arrayIndex < alertEntitiesArray?.count {
                entitiesDict[alertDict["entities"][arrayIndex]["type"].stringValue] = alertDict["entities"][arrayIndex]["label"].stringValue
                arrayIndex++
            }
            let alertService: String? = entitiesDict["service"]
            let alertUser: String? = entitiesDict["user"]
            let alertSeverity: String? = alertDict["severity"][1].stringValue

            let alert = AlertModel(alertUser: alertUser, alertService: alertService, alertTitle: alertTitle, alertReadStatus: alertReadStatus, alertResolutionStatus: alertResolutionStatus, alertDescription: alertDescription, alertDate: alertDate, alertId: alertId, alertSeverity: alertSeverity)
            alerts.append(alert)
            var alertsDictionaryByID = [alertId!: alert]

        }
        println(alerts)
    }
```

As you can see the JSON data is a few levels deep. I have no problem getting to the data and pulling it out. The problem is the "Entities" array may not always have the same data in it. It my have multiple services, it may have no email address, it may have a completely different set of data for the first value of the array.

I am trying to get the email address out. If I could find a way to search for the "user" as with the dictionary data and then when found it would return the array index value to be able to reference it directly because I will never know with index number the user value is part of.

I hope I came across clear enough and someone can help me. --- my next step will be populating a listView with each individual alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding SwiftyJSON and Alamofire to significantly assist with the networking and JSON Serialization.

As far as my issue with the dictionaries within the array I ended up creating a function that iterated through the entities array looking at each dictionary seperately and then performed a Switch statement based on the key="type" to determine if it was the "user" dictionary or the "service" dictionary and then combined the 'type' value, which said if it was a user or a service, with the value of "label", which is the the username or service name, and created a new dictionary out of that which I could then reference to put back into my data model.

```
class func retrieveDataFromEntitiesArray (alertDict: JSON) -> (entitesDict: Dictionary<String, String>, servicesArray: [String]) {
    // Need to create an array object, instead of a JSON object, of the entities array to be able to get a count to run the while against.
    var arrayIndex = 0
    var entitiesDict: Dictionary<String, String> = [:]
    var alertEntitiesArray = alertDict.arrayObject
    var servicesArray = [String]()
    while arrayIndex < alertEntitiesArray?.count {
        var dictKey = alertDict[arrayIndex]["type"].string
        switch (dictKey!) {
        case "user":
            entitiesDict[alertDict[arrayIndex]["type"].stringValue] = alertDict[arrayIndex]["label"].stringValue
        case "service":
            servicesArray.append(alertDict[arrayIndex]["label"].stringValue)
        case "policyRule":
            entitiesDict[alertDict[arrayIndex]["type"].stringValue] = alertDict[arrayIndex]["label"].stringValue
        default:
            println("Nothing Here")
        }
        arrayIndex++
    }
    return (entitiesDict, servicesArray)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also using SwiftyJSON, but using NSURLConnection was easy. Like this method.

```
//MARK: - NSURLConnection Delegate methods


    var responseData : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!)
    {
        self.responseData.length = 0
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!)
    {
        self.responseData.appendData(data)
    }


    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
    {
        if let responseDatas = responseData as NSData? {

            if let jsonResult : NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseDatas, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary? {


                if let dataArray = jsonResult.valueForKeyPath("data") as? NSArray 
                 {

                  if let entitiesArray = dataArray.valueForKeyPath("entities") as? NSArray 
                 {

                 if let firstArray = dataArray[0] 
                 {
                     // access your viewName and types here
                 }                    

                     // Like this method, convert all your parameters and access it.

                }                    
                }
                else
                {
               // Do something here
                }

            }
            else
            {
                 // Do something here

            }
        }
        else
        {
             // Do something here

        }



    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!)
    {
     // Do something here
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. I tried adding this in and I am getting two errors at the last if-let statement
'1. Constant 'firstEntitiesArray' inferred to have type 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected. This one is pointing to firstArray.'
'2. Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type. This one is pointing to dataArray[0].'Can you help me understand how the last if-let statement helps me find the key\values I am looking for? This seems simple enough without swiftyJSON but as I said I am still new so I may not be able to infer something you are expecting I have knowledge of.

Comment: Can you help me understand how the last if-let statement helps me find the key\values I am looking for? This seems simple enough without swiftyJSON but as I said I am still new so I may not be able to infer something you are expecting I have knowledge of.